# Obtener y guardar la respuesta de una api

Tags: angular, typescript, api

comunidad, tengo una duda, tengo una API la cual inserto información, hasta ahí todo bien y este me devuelve él, id de registro de dicha información, lo que requiero es obtener ese, id que se me envía como respuesta una vez ingresado la información a la base de datos.

```js
this.apisInstitucionesService.createInstitucion(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonFInal))).subscribe({
            next: (v) =>{
              if(v != null ){
                this.refreshTable();
                this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Completado', detail: 'Institución creado correctamente.', life: 3000});
              }else{
                this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error Institución no se pudo crear.', life: 3000});
              }
            },
            error: (e) =>{
              this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error al guarda la institución', life: 3000});
              console.error(e);
            }, 
            complete: () => console.info('complete') 
          });
```

la api donde consumo para insertar la informacion es:

```js
//insertar institución
  createInstitucion(json: JSON){
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      "token": environment.token,
    });
    const requestOptions = { headers: this.headers };
    return this.http.post(environment.baseUrl+'api/servicio-social/instituciones/institucion/completa/registrar',json,requestOptions);
  }
```

este me retorna una vez guardada el ID, entonces requiero de ese ID para guardarlo en otra API a la vez.
esta es la respuesta [{"success":193}] solo deseo obtener el id y guardarlo en una variable pero no se como. estuve leyendo que con async/await o HttpParam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías crear una propiedad donde almacenar ese ID.
Podés definirla al inicio de la clase o directamente en el constructor. Así:

```
 ...
 export class appComponent {
 // this.responseId: number | null;
  constructor() {
   // this.responseId: number | null;
   }
  }
```

Elegí la opción que te parezca mejor o estés utilizando en tu proyecto

El valor que obtiene el subscribe, en este caso "`v`" contiene lo que sea que haya retornado el método "`createInstitucion`" (Cabe resaltar que no deberías mezclar dos idiomas, utiliza inglés o español, no ambas), entonces podés obtener el valor de respuesta y después de parsearlo podés asignarle el valor de "success" a la propiedad

```
this.apisInstitucionesService.createInstitucion(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonFInal))).subscribe({
        next: (v) =>{
         ...
         const auxId = JSON.parse(v[0]);
         this.responseID = auxId.success;
         ...
```

y listo, ya podés utilizar `this.responseID` en tu componente

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo @Gramajo Alex, me resirvio de mucha ayuda amigo. gracias por tu ayuda.